# Gulp watch logging that it ran, but my files aren't changing

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Edit: Solved below

Here is my gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minify = require('gulp-minify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var allSassFiles = 'scss/**/*.scss';
var sassFile = gulp.src('./scss/style.scss');
var cssDest = '../wp-content/themes/Jupiter-child/uwkc_assets/css');

var sassify = function() {
  return sassFile.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed', onError: sass.logError}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest + '/prod'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
};

gulp.task('doSass', sassify);

gulp.task('watchSass', function(){
  return gulp.watch(allSassFiles, ['doSass']);
});
```

The sass glob is the variable "allSassFiles".
s
When I run the task "doSass" everything compiles fine. My css changes are represented in the browser.

However when I run the "watchSass" task things only change once, and then further changes are not reflected in the browser. It is like running only one occurrence of "doSass".

What is weird is that in my console I see the start and complete logs for doSass as if everything is running fine. However I don't see any changes being made to my css destination files.

I've tried many things, mixing up what I am returning, changing the glob syntax. Lots of things. For some reason I just can't get the darned thing to work.

Anyone see anything I might be missing? I have a feeling it has to do with what is returned with gulp-sass or sourcemaps, but I don't know enough about those to figure out the answer.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: remove the return from the watch

Comment: also this : var cssDest = '../wp-content/themes/Jupiter-child/uwkc_assets/css'); cant be right

Comment: It is. I am trying to keep all the css files in the child theme of my WP install while the gulp files are in the root. Also I tried removing the return from watch and it didn't seem to do anything. I can try it again.

Comment: Since I assume you are running gulp4.0, try changing to gulp.watch(allSassFiles, sassify);

Comment: I'll try that thanks!

Comment: Hey everyone. Thanks for taking the time to comment. I tried playing with return and also calling the sassify function directly and I am still having the problem. I start the watch, it allows me to make one change, and then future changes aren't coming through. Very weird. I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: And I solved it! I needed to create a new gulp.src object every time apparently. I removed the variable call from the "sassify function" and called gulp.src() every time, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I figured out:

I needed to create a new gulp.src() object every time I ran sassify in the watch runtime apparently. Also I hope I am using those terms right.

I re-wrote:

```
return sassFile.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
```

in the sassify function to:

```
return gulp.src('./scss/style.scss').pipe(sourcemaps.init())
```

This did the trick. It makes sense to me that watch would re-use the same src object referenced in the variable **sassFile** that didn't represent a changed scss file.